Why Tailwind !p-0 class gets automatically converted to p-0?
When building a Vite/Vue3 app, important Tailwind classes (i.e. !p-0) that I assign to elements in my template get automatically stripped from ! and converted to: p-0.
The HTML code itself: <Header class="border-b-0 pt-0 !p-0"> is converted to <Header class="border-b-0 pt-0 p-0"> (but only in production build).
Which specific dependency, or option is causing that? PostCSS? Or is it Tailwind itself?
Adding the class to safelist in tailwind.config.js seems to prevent it (safelist: ['!p-0']), but I'm rather curious what exactly is altering it in the first place. I don't have anything in my tailwind.config.ts that could be related to ! stripping:
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

export default {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ['./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  // safelist: ['!p-0'],
  theme: {...},
} satisfies Config

Tailwind version: 3.3.5. PostCSS version: 8.4.13. Vite version: 3.2.7.
My postcss.config.js:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

My vite.config.ts:
(...)
plugins: [
  vue(),
  vueJsx(),
  vueI18nPlugin({
    runtimeOnly: false,
  }),
 ],
(...)
build: {
  lib: isStandalone
  ? undefined
  : {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.ts'),
    name: 'foo',
    fileName: 'foo',
    formats: ['umd'],
  },
  rollupOptions: isStandalone
  ? {
    output: {
      inlineDynamicImports: true,
      entryFileNames: '[name].js',
      assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]'
    },
  }
  : undefined,
},
(...)


In Tailwind, there is a built-in purge process by default. This means it only keeps the classes in the production code that it detects in files with the specified syntax. Important that the class name is clearly discoverable and not dynamically constructed. For example: let className = 'p-0';  if (shouldImportant) className = '!' + className;

Additionally, all classes added to the safelist are included in the production build, regardless of usage. If it works well with the safelist, then the issue lies with the detection, as mentioned above. The class name may not be clearly defined. It's also possible that the file where the !p-0 class is used is not included in the content prop of the tailwind.config.js file with the correct syntax.

off: mode: 'jit' is a deprecated parameter starting from version 3.x.

@rozsazoltan It is clearly defined: <Header class="border-b-0 pt-0 !p-0">. The problem is not that Tailwind does not generate !pb-0 class, but rather that my HTML code gets altered to <Header class="border-b-0 pt-0 p-0"> - is it also Tailwind doing that...?

Ah, I see. Please include this in the question, as it wasn't clear without an example.

I tried to reproduce the issue, but neither in development mode nor during the build process does it remove the ! from the p-0 class name. Could you provide a working reproduction with a https://codesandbox.io?

@rozsazoltan It's a bit complicated to come up with a minimal reproducible example. That class is passed down to a component from external library (npm dependency). But not only that, the whole app is later imported by another app. And in that parent app the ! seems to be purged, so that the compiled HTML in the browser is using the p-0 class stripped from !.

If I remember correctly, although I couldn't quickly find official documentation to support this, in JIT mode (what default from 3.x), if an HTML file contains a class like !p-0 but the CSS only has the p-0 class without !, Tailwind CSS will help by correcting the class name in the output code. You need to add the path to this external file to the content parameter in tailwind.config.js alongside the src folder so that Tailwind CSS can scan your file during the build and include the !p-0 class in the CSS.

@rozsazoltan Yea, that sounds like a reasonable explanation. So either safelist fixes it, or adding the imported app to the content. Thanks for the help!
Oddly enough, adding safelist has no impact on my app (compiled HTML is not altered and !p-0 is genereated in the CSS either way), but it does have an impact on the app that's importing my app (prevents it from altering the HTML of my app).
